# Differentiate between group of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to differentiate between a group of buttons? Given the following buttons.

```
<div id="slideout_inner">
<h2>Select Size</h2>
<p id="group1">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Small $2.50</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Medium $3.50</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Large $4.50</button> 
</p>
<h2>Select Milk</h2>
<p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Full</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Trim</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Soy</button>
</p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Done</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block       cancelOrder">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
```

If I do the following I can highlight the selected button in `group1`

```
    $('#group1 button').on("click", function(){
    $('#group1 button').removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
    $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass('btn-primary');
    })
```

I expect the button list to be dynamic so I want to select buttons with `<p>` to highlight separately so remove the #group selector and just highlight buttons within each `<p>`.

So in this example I could highlight `Medium $3.50` and then highlight `Soy` independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("button").on("click", function () {
        $(this).siblings("button").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
        $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass('btn-primary');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting only children of the parent `<p>` instead of all `#group1 button`s.

```
$(this).parent().find("button").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
```

This way you are only accessing a subset of `button`s within the parent element, instead of running the query on the entire DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to select all sibling elements so you can find all sibling elements of the clicked `.btn` element:

```js
$("p .btn").on("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings(".btn").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
    $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass('btn-primary');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideout_inner">
<h2>Select Size</h2>
<p id="group1">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Small $2.50</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Medium $3.50</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Large $4.50</button> 
</p>
<h2>Select Milk</h2>
<p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Full</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Trim</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Soy</button>
</p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Done</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block       cancelOrder">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :contains() selector to identify which button is clicked. and then use the siblings() selector.

```
$( "button:contains('Small $2.50')" ).siblings()
```

Better approach would be to use different classes for each group. But the above should get you going.